# Flow Trigger Framework

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, lightning-flow-builder

We have various Apex trigger framework resource available. It's great. Now Salesforce launches trigger capabilities within beloved Lightning flows. If somebody has to migrate his/her Apex trigger to Flow trigger, does he really a trigger framework inside Flows or he does not need at all? If yes, what would be it?

Comment: Interesting question, but I suspect this might get marked down as opinion based.